# Gitlab coverage badge from nyc istanbul cobertura xml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, badge, nyc

i have a public adonis js boilerplate in gitlab and i am struggling with the coverage badge as it shows "unknown"
the repo link: https://gitlab.com/XanXus961/adonis-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

The coverage badge does not work with the cobertura report but with [the coverage keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#coverage).

You should add this to your `test` job:

```yaml
  coverage: '/Statements\s*: \d+\.\d+/'
```

It should match [this line](https://gitlab.com/XanXus961/adonis-boilerplate/-/jobs/2083914619#L104), Gitlab should do the rest.